# Is there a way to get android studio (debug signing) to work both for work office and home office?

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1

I have a development environment at work office which is fairly similar that at my home office. We are using github (mostly for storing last changes (in a farly simple way)). But when we work on projects both with Microsoft and Google signing we run into trouble when the SHA-1 is different for the work office environment and the home office environment (in debug mode).

1. Why isn't the SHA-1 bound to the developer (as I sign into Android Studio) than to the physical computer where I compile my app ?
2. Is there a way I can enter the SHA-1 (or its complementary) in android studio so it is signed with the same key for both home and work office ?

RG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Android Studio itself does not use developer accounts. Perhaps you are referring to the git login but that is only related to git, and fully optional so the keys cannot be bound to that.
2. Yes, on every new installation a `debug.keystore` file is generated with a signing key that is used for every debug build.
   The file can be found at:
   `C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore` on PC or;
   `~/.android/debug.keystore` on Mac.
   Simply copy this file from one machine and replace the one on the other machine and both installations will now use the same signing key for all debug builds!

Comment: Thanx for the answer.

I have found a solution where I have used a signing method with a common keyfile. This works, where I have similar copies at home office and work office.